# iPhone: Is there a way to loadFromNib AND have a reuseIdentifier?

Tags: uitableview, nib, reusability, identifier

I am thinking about this problem now for very long.

I try to use different types of cells in my table, that each have their own cell controller and have a reuseIdentifier AND load from NIB.

The problem boils down to this: You can either init a Cell via 
[UITableViewCell initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:] or via [NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:].

Do i overlook something or is there a possibility to have both: load from nib and use reuseIdentifier?

Comment: Here's your answer --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413993/loading-a-reusable-uitableviewcell-from-a-nib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking a question can sometimes lead you to the right track :I

The answer can be found here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1664267?threadID=1664267

Comment: i managed to retrieve the original url by unencoding the url... try the new one. i just edited my post

Answer (score 0):

I am hopping you are using customized `UITableViewCell`. `reuseIdentifier` is readonly property so you couldn't set it but there are two ways,

1) Open your custom nib in Interface Builder and set `identifier` property and use this same string as `reuseIdentifier` while calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifie`r.

2) Pass `reuseIdentifier` in constructor of you nib file and then call its base constructor there which takes style and identifier as arguments.