# Why does Interface Builder not show me class-specific attributes?

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder, nib

I am trying to implement Tim Keating's answer from here: [Loading a Reusable UITableViewCell from a Nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413993/loading-a-reusable-uitableviewcell-from-a-nib)

I made a view XIB and assigned the view's Class to UITableViewCell.

When I go to the Attributes Inspector though, all I see are the "Simulated User Interface Elements" and "View" sections. I do not see a "Table View Cell" section like in his answer :( I tried closing and reloading, it still won't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always select an empty XIB and pick a `UITableViewCell` element from the object library.