# UITableView is redrawing only some of custom cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview

For quite a bit of time I am struggled with a kinda stupid problem. Hope someone can give me a hand.

UITableView is being implemented. The UITableViewCell is drawn in .xib and connected to a textEditCell property.

in the main program there is a simple code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return textEditCell;

}
```

Yet when the view is drawn, only some cells (after the view is started - last cell) is drawn. If the view is dragged beyond the top end of the screen, the top cell is been drawn, the bottom one is gone; when dragging to the bottom the behaviour is opposite.

Given the example [in Apple cookbook](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1)? that is Listing 5-7. what am I doing wrong?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

What is described in *Listing 5-7* only works if you only have **one** cell of that kind in your table. If you need many copies of that same cell then you should use the technique described in *Listing 5-5*.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're creating a single instance of a cell and trying to assign it to many rows. In the Apple cookbook you have a fixed number of custom cells, called cell0, cell1 instanced separately in the builder.

You would need to create another nib file to create your cells. Also remember about reusing cells - otherwise you will definitely have memory problems.

Comment: Estarriol, thanks for the answer. Creating another nib seems to be the only way; though it doesn't seem to be logical - why can't I have them all in one nib? I'm not mentioning that nib is loaded for every cell - that is a redundant operation, isn't it?

Another question is: where is a new instance of the reused cell created in, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202471/is-it-possible-to-design-nscell-subclasses-in-interface-builder ?
Or the newly reloaded nib gives a new object?