# iPhone - "Class" may not respond to "method"

Tags: iphone, warnings

I am building a simple Navigation-based app using tables.

I have a custom "UITableViewCell" to customize the table cell data attached below.

```
@interface NewsCell : UITableViewCell 
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *newsTitle;
}
- (void)setNewsLabel:(NSString *)title;
@end
```

And then in my RootViewController, I set the text of the label "newsTitle" in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method as follows.

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
MyIdentifier = @"NewsCell";

NewsCell *cell = (NewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) 
{
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsCell" owner:self options:nil];
   cell = newsCell;
}

[cell setNewsLabel:@"hello testing"];
return cell;
```

When I run this, the app runs fine, but I get "NewsCell may not respond to '-setNewsLabel:'" warning.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Is the identifier string in xib as the same as "MyIdentifier"?

Answer (score 1):

In `RootViewController.m`, you need to `#import "NewsCell.h".

Or, stick `#import "NewsCell.h"` in your project's PCH (pre-compiled header) file.

The underlying issue is that the compiler only knows about methods that it has previously seen when parsing the header files (or ones in the PCH).

Answer (score 0):

Where does the variable `newsCell` come from? Is it really of type `NewsCell`?

Comment: ... cleaned, but still getting this warning. very strange.

Comment: Hi tob, I declared "newsCell" in the RootViewController.h

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController 
{
 IBOutlet NewsCell *newsCell;
}

Comment: Did you make sure to connect the IBOutlet in IB?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the nib, but not assigning it to anything.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202471/is-it-possible-to-design-nscell-subclasses-in-interface-builder) to create it right.

Comment: I tried one of the suggested answers, but to no avail. This thing is driving me bananas!

Comment: Question, were you following this tutorial: http://blancer.com/tutorials/i-phone/25543/iphone-programming-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/ ??