# What is the easiest way to custom NSTableView cell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nscell, nstextfieldcell

I'm an iOS developer. I recently started my Mac project, but I found that unlike UITableViewCell, which is a subclass of UIView, the cell of NSTableView is NSCell, and I even can't create it in IB. I wonder if there are some easy ways to create subclass like NSTextFieldCell to put it into the NSTableView.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean you can't create it in interface builder? Just make a custom cell and drag it into a table view.

Comment: Have a look at my [approach to use a subview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884265/how-to-setup-a-nstableview-with-a-custom-cell-using-a-subview).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the open source [PXListView](https://github.com/Perspx/PXListView) class on [Github](http://github.com)

This has a `PXListViewCell` that you can use as an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! PXListView is awesome!